# Tmux - Detach client fails if using bash startup script

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

Typically, I use a bash script to create my tmux session (split panes, set PWD, call commands, etc.). This works great, except if I try to run `tmux detach-client`. It will fail to detach, instead just adds on extra windows and splits everything up weirdly. Not what is expected.

To duplicate: launch a terminal, and run the script. Then create another terminal in another tab (like in gnome-terminal). Run the script again and it will attach as expected. Finally run `tmux detach-client`, and see the results.

Here is a simpler [POC script](https://gist.github.com/beeryardtech/7163c1570fbe3ebc86fb361bff914948), and this is the original ones: [vimui](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beeryardtech/scripts/master/bash/vimui.sh) and [tmuxhome](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beeryardtech/scripts/master/bash/tmuxhome.sh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be just calling `tmux detach` gets confused about which session. So calling providing the session name works like a charm.